# Ubuntu sendmail relay with username and password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail

I have a Ubuntu server which I want to setup a mail server on. Now, I've heard that sendmail is the only mail server that supports a relay server.
Why I need a relay server is because my Ubuntu Server is hosted from home and my ISP requires all mails from a mail server to go through their relay. The relay also have to authenticate with a username and password. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: AFAIK Sendmail/Postfix/Exim support SMTP AUTH.